# What version of jQuery should I actually use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So a few months ago, there was a time I didn't actually need jQuery for anything, and almost forgot it.

Then I woke up. So, I headed to http://jquery.com/download/ just to get extremely confused about what actually happened.

The last thing I remember is using version 1.8.3, and the page tells me that

> The jQuery 1.x line had major changes as of jQuery 1.9.0. We strongly recommend that you also use the jQuery Migrate plugin if you are upgrading from pre-1.9 versions of jQuery or need to use plugins that haven't yet been updated.

Okay? The jQuery 1.x line? Well, what line was 1.9.0 then?

The 2.x notes are relatively simple to understand, if you don't need support for IE8 and under, go for it. But really, what is 1.11.0?

- Does it support older versions of IE? 8 to be accurate.
- Do I need to use the migration plugin if I use an old plugin?
- What am I missing?

As I have no idea of which version I should use, I'll just stick with the 1.8.3 until I know what I should use.

Comment: This will be useful… http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/

Comment: @buzzsawddog It doesn't answer the question, why did the version jump from 1.9.1 to 1.11?

Comment: We still use 1.11 (updated from 1.10 friday) due to the fact that there are a few customers using IE 8 (its not going to be easy to kill off).  Look at the plugins you may be using, I have run into a few that only work with 1.8.3.  1.9 was a major change so…    Be prepared to change plugins if thats the case.

Comment: It did not jump from 1.9 to 1.11,   We used 1.10 for quite some time

Comment: @Christian: It didn't, why do you think that? *"Well, what line was 1.9.0 then"* 1.x, because it stats with 1. What happened in jQuery 1.9 is that a lot of deprecated methods have finally been removed.

Comment: @buzzsawddog Well, the main point is still the same. 1.10 < 1.9 ?

Comment: @Christian: `10` is larger than `9`, so `1.11 > 1.10 > 1.9 > 1.8`. jQuery uses semantic versioning: http://semver.org/ (I guess, although minor versions should not actually contain breaking changes, which 1.9 does).

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, now I understand.

Comment: so software versioning can be strange.  IMO they should have done 1.01 -1.09 then 1.1 but…     We are not looking at decimals, 1.10 is one point ten being larger than one point nine. 1.1 != 1.10

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[From the jQuery blog post on the releases of 1.9.0 and 2.0](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/):

- jQuery 1.9 and 2.0 have the same API. Several deprecated features
  such as $.browser have been removed from both versions. It’s all laid
  out in the jQuery 1.9 upgrade guide.
- jQuery 1.9 runs on Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 (“oldIE”), just like
  previous versions. Consider it a cleaner, slimmer, modern-API upgrade
  from jQuery 1.8.
- jQuery 2.0 will not run on oldIE. As a result of removing several
  layers of barnacle-encrusted code, it will be both faster and smaller
  than jQuery 1.9.

So to answer your questions

1. 1.11.0 still supports IE 6, 7 and 8, the difference of >= 1.9.0 is in the api
2. Migrate plugin can be used to detect if your code is using deprecated or removed features, maybe using it to detect whether your old plugin is using such features would be recommendable
3. You were missing the blog post that explained these changes

Answer (score 3):

If you're starting to use jQuery (you weren't using it in your project), and you need support for IE8 an earlier, use the latest version, 1.11. This version belongs to the 1.x line, as the number indicates. The only difference between 1.x and 2.x is IE support.

Comment: So on new projects, 1.11, and if I update some projects I've made in the past, 1.9.1?

Comment: If you're going to use 1.9, you can also use 1.11. The big differences came with 1.9 version. What the jQuery team tells you is that, if you're changing from an earlier version to a version greater than 1.9, you can use the jQuery Migrate plugin, though you may not need it, it would depend. If you didn't use extra plugins, you may not need it.