# jquery.ajax post put methods in ie11 with empty body

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post, put

I am using ie11 and jquery 3.2.1. I also used older versions of jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='lib/jquery.js'></script>
    <script>
        function onclick() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "test",
                cache: false,
                data: {name: "John", location: "Boston"}
            }).done(function (msg) {
                console.log("Data Saved: " + msg);
            });
        }
        $(function () {
            $('button').click(onclick);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="test" >Click me</button>
</body>
```

works everywhere except ie. ie does not send the data. However, if in the developer tools I change the Document mode to 9, the data is sent. Does anyone knows how to enable jquery.ajax post and put in ie11?

Best regards,
Marian

illustration for ie11 with empty request body:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I change the mode to 9 the same script send a request with a body:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried your code in my local machine. But it is working fine. please describe issue you are facing with a screen capture

Comment: I added the illustrations

Comment: Try using the latest version of jquery. Only IE11 is supported now... IF you are developing for a legacy intranet site that requires a lower emulation mode set via Enterprise Site Mode lists, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289583/what-version-of-jquery-should-i-actually-use

Comment: I just tried jquery 3.2.1. it does not help.